# The Minimum CDF of non-independent random variables

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable, joint-distribution, cumulative-distribution-function

How can I find the CDF for $F_{X,Y}=\{x,x\}$ if $X,Y$ are **not-independent**. In other words, what will be $Pr\{min(X,Y)<x\}$ if $X,Y$ are **not-independent**?

If I already know the individual CDF of both $X$ and $Y$, i.e.  $F_{X}(x)$ and  $F_{Y}(x)$, can they be useful to compute the $Pr\{min(X,Y)<x\}$, where $X,Y$ are **not-independent variables**?

Comment: As I pointed out in a comment to the duplicate, your question has already been fully answered there.

Comment: I guess this Question is different from the previous one. This one is about dependent variables.

Comment: The comment whuber refers to explains that it applies to dependent variates as well. I suggest you modify your title at the other question to drop the "independent" but leave the word in the body text, and then at the end of the question add that you're interested in the dependent case as well.